# Angular ng-repeat vs data-ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Is there any difference between `ng-repeat` or `data-ng-repeat` in Angularjs?

I believe there are other directives with `data` prefix as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

They are aliases.  Angular allows both in order to name a directive.  The `data-ng-repeat` allows the HTML to be validated through validators that do not understand Angular.

The documentation is [here with directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

This is from the docs:

> Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine
>   which elements match which directives. We typically refer to
>   directives by their case-sensitive camelCase normalized name (e.g.
>   ngModel). However, since HTML is case-insensitive, we refer to
>   directives in the DOM by lower-case forms, typically using
>   dash-delimited attributes on DOM elements (e.g. ng-model).

And all these are valid:

```
  <span ng-bind="name"></span> <br/>
  <span ng:bind="name"></span> <br/>
  <span ng_bind="name"></span> <br/>
  <span data-ng-bind="name"></span> <br/>
  <span x-ng-bind="name"></span> <br/>
```

AFAIK, you can use these naming conventions in *any* directive that Angular parses.