# Iterate using Javascript to display multiple images in Html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS for a webapp, I have a set of images stored on disk and I'm using rest services to retrieve the paths of the images on disk. Now on the client side I have an object which is an array containing the paths of the images.

I would like to know how to iterate this array using javascript on the html to display all the images that this array contains.

This is the code I tried but no luck so far:

```
<div id="products" data-ng-repeat="product in products">


<img alt=""  data-ng-src="{{product.pathToImage}}" height="300" width="200px">



</div>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?  What sample code can you show us that might help?

Comment: And where is your javascript code? Have you looked at your console?

Comment: Is your view attached to your controller?

Comment: Yes sorry, I have checked to the console and I got  Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a <- productsFactoryHelper     .So apparently the problem is related to minification not to the code itself, anyway the ng-repeat should go in the element that repeats as James Waddington said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeat should go on the element that repeats rather than the parent - try this:

```
<div id="products">
    <img alt="" data-ng-repeat="product in products" data-ng-src="{{product.pathToImage}}" height="300" width="200px">
</div>
```

Edit - corrected

Answer (score 0):

I think that the attribute is ng-repeat rather than data-ng-repeat, have you the products at your $scope?

```
<div id="products" ng-repeat="product in products">
    <img alt="" ng-src="{{product.pathToImage}}" height="300" width="200px">
</div>
```

Comment: Actually data-ng-repeat is the official way.

Comment: @Mikey I didn't know it, where can I find the official way? Because I was using this documentation -> https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.9/docs/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Here is some on the Angular page: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive and there was also a topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862713/angular-ng-repeat-vs-data-ng-repeat. Don't worry you are using the right documentation :)